# How to find all cluster/accumulation points of a given sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

> Let U={$x_n$=($\frac{1}{n}$,(-1)$^n\frac{n-1}{n}$) :n$\in\mathbb{N}$
>   }.Find all cluster points of the set U and prove rigoriously.

First of all, the definition of a cluster point:

> **x**$\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a cluster/accumulation point of set U$\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ if every
>   punctured neighbourhood of **x** B'(**x**, r) contains elements from the set U.

**What I've done:**

Let's take a look at the components $\frac{1}{n}$ and (-1)$^n\frac{n-1}{n}$ separately. It is quite obvious that $\lim_{n\to_\infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$ and that $(-1)^n\frac{n-1}{n}$ diverges. In addition, its subsequences $(-1)\frac{n-1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}-1$ and $\frac{n-1}{n}=1-\frac{1}{n}$  converge to -1 and 1 respectively. Thus my claim is that the cluster points of set U are points (0,1) and (0,-1). Next it needs to be proven in a formal way.

Since  ($\frac{1}{n}$, $1-\frac{1}{n}$) converges to (0, 1), $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists$M such that ||$x_n$-(0,1)||<$\epsilon$, when n>M.

On the other hand, since  ($\frac{1}{n}$, $1-\frac{1}{n}$) converges to (0, 1), for every neighbourhood U of (0,1) there exists N$\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n$$\in$U whenever n$\geq$N. This implies directly(?) that (0,1) is a cluster point of U (?).

Similarly, since  ($\frac{1}{n}$, $\frac{1}{n}-1$) converges to (0, -1), for every neighbourhood U of (0,-1) there exists N$\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n$$\in$U whenever n$\geq$N..?

Lastly, it must be shown that (0,-1) and (0,1) are ***the only*** cluster points of the set U. By contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we show that $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$ are the only cluster points of the set
\begin{align*}
U=\left\{x_n=\left(\frac{1}{n},(-1)^n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right):n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}
\end{align*}

> We argue by contradiction: Assuming $P=(x,y)$ different to $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$ is a cluster point, we prove there is a punctured disc 
>   $B(P,r)$ which does not contain a point of $U$, thus violating the claim of $P$ being a cluster point.

At first we take a look at the points $x_n$ of $U$. We observe, that for each $\varepsilon>0$ the points

\begin{align*}
x_{2n}&=\left(\frac{1}{2n},1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)\in B((0,1),\varepsilon)\qquad\qquad &2n\geq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\\
\text{and}\qquad\qquad &\\
x_{2n+1}&=\left(\frac{1}{2n+1},-1+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)\in B((0,-1),\varepsilon)\qquad\qquad &2n+1\geq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}
 \end{align*}

We observe: For each $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N(\varepsilon)\in\mathbb{N}$  so that for all $n>N(\varepsilon)$ the point $x_n$ is either element of $B((0,1),\varepsilon)$ or $B((0,-1),\varepsilon)$.

> Now assume a point $P=(x,y)$ different to $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$ is given. We consider a punctured disc $B(P,r)$ with center $P$ and radius $r$ less than the minimum distance to $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$.
>
> We choose $\varepsilon>0$ so that
>   \begin{align*}
> B(P,r)\cap B((0,1),\varepsilon)=\emptyset\qquad\text{and}\qquad B(P,r)\cap B((0,-1),\varepsilon)=\emptyset
> \end{align*}
>
> According to the arguments above we can find $N(\varepsilon)\in\mathbb{N}$ so that
>
> $$x_n\in \left(B((0,1),\varepsilon\right)\cup B((0,-1),\varepsilon)\qquad\qquad\qquad n\geq N(\varepsilon)$$
>
> This way it is guaranteed that at most finitely many members $x_n, 1\leq n<N(\varepsilon)$ can be elements of the punctured disc $B(P,r)$.

We now *shrink* the punctured disc to also exclude these finitely many points $x_n, 1\leq n<N(\varepsilon)$.

> We consider a radius $r_{N(\varepsilon)}$ less than the minimum positive distance from the center $P$ to the points $\{x_1,\ldots,x_N(\varepsilon)\}$ and less than $r$. The so constructed punctured disc contains no members of $U$
>   \begin{align*}
> B(P,r_{N(\varepsilon)})\cap U=\emptyset
> \end{align*}
>   showing that $P$ is not a cluster point.

[image]

*Note:* When requiring $r_{N(\varepsilon)}$ to be less than the minimum *positive* distance we also respect a situation whereby one point of $U$ is  $P$.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help, but I don't think we necessarily need to involve neighbourhoods so much. Let B={(0,1),(0,-1)} and A be the set of all cluster points of the set U. Let's now show that there are no other cluster points by proving A=B. I have already shown that B$\subset$A, so now it suffices to show that A$\subset$B i.e. if x$\in$A, then x$\in$B

Comment: Why it is guaranteed that at most finitely many members xn,1≤n<N(ε) can be elements of the punctured disc B'(P,r)? Could you please eleborate from there?

Comment: @1_likeMaths: All elements $x_n$ with $n\geq N(\varepsilon)$ are inside an $\varepsilon$-disc either of $(0,1)$ or of $(0,-1)$. Since we have $r>0$ chosen so that $B(P,r)$ has empty intersection with these discs, there are $x_1,\ldots,x_{N(\varepsilon)}$ left which could be within $B(P,r)$. --> Draw a little diagram to better see what's going on! I'm pretty sure it will help.

Comment: Is it correct that($\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}$)$\in$B((1,0),$\epsilon$) if $n\geq\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and that($\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}-1$)$\in$B((-1,0),$\epsilon$) if $n+1\geq\frac{1}{\epsilon}$?

Comment: @1_likeMaths: No, no,  of course not! :-) Typos corrected! Thanks! I've added a diagram which should help to clarify the situation.

Comment: Shouldn't r=½min{dist(P,(0,1)), dist(P,(0,-1))}?

Comment: @1_likeMaths: This is a good choice. In fact any distance less than the minimum distance is ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45703/discussion-between-1-likemaths-and-markus-scheuer).